# After installing VS 2017, 2013 code compare colors are unreadable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

I've installed Visual Studio 2017, and when I opened VS 2013, and attempted to do a code compare, it looks like this:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? Are there settings that I can update to make the colors more reader-friendly?**

Comment: I had this happen as well. In VS2017, if you go to `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> General` you can choose your color theme. I changed mine to Blue, hit OK, then went back in and changed it to Dark and it seemed to resolve the issue for me. Definitely a hack, seemed to work for me though.

Comment: @peinearydevelopment which VS?

Comment: appreciate the tip but i need it to be dark for my eyes, the blue theme is almost the same as light

Comment: Thats why you change it back.

Comment: i tried that without luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem on Visual Studio 2017 !

I found a fix, that might also help on VS2013 : **Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors**. Select **Text Editor** in the "Show settings for" dropdown, and look for an item relative to CodeCompare (in my case that was **Code Compare Symbol Difference**). You can set a more appropriate foreground and background color here.